# big note Text Field, need Line Breaking

Tags: ios, uitextfield

i have a note Textfield with  width 280 and height 100, i can only write to one/First Line...
 i need a Line Breaking for this Text Field... how can i do this....

this are my settings for the Text Field:

```
_notizField.layer.cornerRadius=0.0f;
        _notizField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        _notizField.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:22/255.0f green:126/255.0f blue:251/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
        _notizField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0;
        _notizField.enabled = NO;
```

thank for your help

Comment: You can't. You should be using UITextView instead.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaking is not possible in a `UITextField`. There is an alternate option to use a `UITextView`. It allows line breaking and is also used to show large amount of texts like paragraphs. You can create a `UITextView` as follows:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
myTextView.text = @"some text";
[self addSubview:myTextView];
[myTextView sizeToFit];
```

Line break is introduced by writing `\n` in your NSString i.e. myTextView.text

This is how you implement line break in a UITextView

```
NSString *aStr = [timeCodeArray objectAtIndex:textNumber];
textView.text = [aStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```